# kernel 4.17 pass argument to new system call to struct pt_regs * doesnt' work

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I wrote simple hook that replace the kill system call with my one and also craete a new one and add it to the end of sys_call_table pointer everything is work fine except that when I call my system call but i can't pass argument to it  and also I cant call the kill system call from kernel space it just do nothing I must say that in kernel 4.15 it worked good but in the 4.17 kernel i had to change few things
any way this is the code of my new system call

```
asmlinkage long comu(struct pt_regs *t)
{
    printk("%d\n",t.bx);
}
```

and when I call it from python with ctypes and send it the number 0 or 1 it print very height number
and this is my version of the sys_kill

```
asmlinkage long our_sys_kill(struct pt_regs *t)
 {
    printk("process was killed%ld\n",t->bx);

    for( i=0;i<10;i++)
    { 
        if(p[i]==t->bx&&t->cx!=2)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return orig_kill(t);

 }
```

Comment: This should not compile: `printk("%d\n",t.bx);` as t is a pointer.

Comment: @Gerhardh it had compiled and it also prrinted it value but it was vary height and it should be zero or one